# How is the Promise design Pattern able to detect when a Mongoose function fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code which execute the then block if the mongoose update functions work:

```
  Promise.all([
User.update({id: req.body.myId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.friendId}}).exec(),
User.update({id: req.body.friendId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.myId}}).exec()
  ])

 .then(function (results) {
console.log(results[0]);
console.log(results[1]);
 })

 .catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
res.status(500).send('Unable to start chat')
// or next(err) if you use a global express error handler. 
 });
```

After watching one too many tutorials on Promises in JavaScript, I learned that the catch gets triggered if there is a reject. However, does Mongoose have rejects when something fails in it. I'm not quite sure how to word it, but does Mongoose consider Promises when it comes to updating?

Comment: Also, I'am not using bluebird, co nor Q

Comment: Whenever mongoose would have called a callback with an error as the first argument, it now rejects the promise.

Comment: Then why does bluebird recommend you to do this : Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'))

Comment: Maybe that's from a time when  mongoose did not support promises itself? Also, mongoose's implementation is by far inferior to bluebird's, so it makes sense to cast them

Comment: Thank you Bergi! Makes sense.

Comment: You can also plugging in your own Promises library like `bluebird` this is in Mongoose version 4.1.0. `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');` check the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: J.Arturo Covarrubias, if i do that then i wouldnt have to call Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose')) ? do they accomplish the same purpose ?